# Modal Popup not working

Tags: angularjs, popup, modal-dialog

Good day! I am making a popup on my save button but it seems to be not working. I copied the code on JSFiddle sample but when I run it on my laptop its not working 
Here is the result on my browser

[image]

here is my code

```
  <body>
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl" class="container">

  <button ng-click="toggleModal()" class="btn btn-default">Save</button>

  <modal title="Saved!" visible="showModal">
    <form role="form">
     <p>
     Time Settings Succesfully Saved!
     </p>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" visible="closeModal">Ok</button>
    </form>
  </modal>
</div>
<script>
var mymodal = angular.module('mymodal', []);

mymodal.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.showModal = false;
    $scope.toggleModal = function(){
        $scope.showModal = !$scope.showModal;
    };
  });

mymodal.directive('modal', function () {
    return {
      template: '<div class="modal fade">' + 
          '<div class="modal-dialog">' + 
            '<div class="modal-content">' + 
              '<div class="modal-header">' + 
                '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>' + 
                '<h4 class="modal-title">{{ title }}</h4>' + 
              '</div>' + 
              '<div class="modal-body" ng-transclude></div>' + 
            '</div>' + 
          '</div>' + 
        '</div>',
      restrict: 'E',
      transclude: true,
      replace:true,
      scope:true,
      link: function postLink(scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.title = attrs.title;

        scope.$watch(attrs.visible, function(value){
          if(value == true)
            $(element).modal('show');
          else
            $(element).modal('hide');
        });

        $(element).on('shown.bs.modal', function(){
          scope.$apply(function(){
            scope.$parent[attrs.visible] = true;
          });
        });

        $(element).on('hidden.bs.modal', function(){
          scope.$apply(function(){
            scope.$parent[attrs.visible] = false;
          });
        });
      }
    };
  });
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: link to the original (working) fiddle?

Comment: @reto here is the link of the original fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/alexsuch/RLQhh/

Comment: @Sajeetharan the result when i run the code on my browser is on the image above